# R stringr Parse Cases Letters

Tags: r, stringr

```
HAVE            WANT1   WANT2
CLStephen Five  CL      Stephen Five
RTQQuent Lou X  RTQ     Quent Lou X
```

There is a data entry error on our school system, I have col 'HAVE' and wish to separate it into 'WANT1' and 'WANT2'

```
WANT1 = take the first n-1 CAPITAL letters
WANT2 = take the remaining letters
```

Comment: @Friede it is shown in the data and described below

Comment: By looking at the raw text in the 'edit' window, there were tabs in there separating the columns. Unfortunately Stackoverflow doesn't respect them in the output shown. I've aligned the text in accordance with the tabs now.

Answer (score 2):

An attempt in both *stringr* and base R:

```
x <- c("CLStephen Five","RTQQuent Lou X")

library(stringr) 
str_remove(x, "[A-Z][^A-Z].+")
#[1] "CL"  "RTQ"
str_extract(x, "[A-Z][^A-Z].+")
#[1] "Stephen Five" "Quent Lou X" 

sub("[A-Z][^A-Z].+", "", x)
#[1] "CL"  "RTQ"
sub("[A-Z]+([A-Z][^A-Z].+)", "\\1", x)
#[1] "Stephen Five" "Quent Lou X"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with the new `tidyr::separate_wider_regex`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(have = c("CLStephen Five","RTQQuent Lou X"))

# --------------------------  
separate_wider_regex(
  df,
  cols = have,
  patterns = c(
    want1 = "[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])",
    want2 = "[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z].*"))

# A tibble: 2 × 2 ---------
  want1 want2       
  <chr> <chr>       
1 CL    Stephen Five
2 RTQ   Quent Lou X
```